# Why is System.Linq.Dynamic.Core OrderBy not working with ImmutableArray?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I am trying to use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core with an ImmutableArray for dynamic OrderBy but I get the following exception:

`` Expression of type 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[$customType]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[$customType]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[$customType] OrderByDescending[$customType,Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[$customType], System.Func`2[$customType,System.Int32])' (Parameter 'arg0') ``

Why is this? Have they defined specific validations for Immutable types? Normal OrderBy is perfectly capable of sorting it. Should this be submitted to them as a feature request or am I missing something obvious? Once it is cast to a List it works like a charm.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast to a List"? That isn't possible...

Comment: Yeah you are right, this is just a language barrier thing, I just meant when I try to do the same on a List<T> it works. I've checked your github issue and thank you for looking into it, I think this will be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in .Net (Core), specifically in the validation of arguments for `Expression.Call`.

Ultimately the first parameter is validated by calling [`TypeUtils.AreReferenceAssignable`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq.Expressions/System/Dynamic/Utils/TypeUtils.cs,b1431d1174dcc305) and the code assumes that a value type cannot be (reference) assignable to a non-value type, and `ImmutableArray` is a value type because it is implemented with a `struct`.

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41716) on github to see what others think.